# Explain pipe and fork output

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I am dealing with pipe and fork in Linux for the first time and I would be happy if someone could explain to me the output of the following program: (which line of code causes the output and is it through the son process or the parent process)

```
int main(){                              //1
    int ipc[2];                          //2
    pipe(ipc);                           //3
    write(2, "start\n", 6);              //4
    if (fork()) {                        //5
        sleep(1);                        //6
        char c;                          //7
        do {                             //8
            read(ipc[0], &c, 1);         //9
            write(1, &c, 1);             //10
        } while (c != '\n');             //11
        write(1, "if\n", 3);             //12
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);            //13
    }                                    //14
    else {                               //15
        write(ipc[1], "else1\n", 6);     //16
        write(1, "else2\n", 6);          //17
    }                                    //18
    write(1, "done\n", 5);               //19
    return 0;                            //20
}                                        //21
```

The output of the program is:

```
start
else2
done
else1
if
done
```

Comment: What difficulties specifically do you have? It should be easy to see which lines contain the output strings. `ipc` (common abbreviation for "inter process communication") is a pipe, so everything related to `ipc` is communication between the processes. `write(2,...)` writes to `stderr`, `write(1, ...)` to stdout. The `if (fork())` branch is ececuted in the parent process both when `fork` is successful and when it failed. The `else` branch is executed in the child process. Everything after the `if/else` will be ececuted by both processes.

Comment: Understand which line is responsible for each output line and understand whether it was performed through the parent process or through the son process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork()` creates a child process executing the same code as the original process. If it succeeds, the only difference between your two processes is that:

- in the original process, `fork` will return a non-zero value (i.e. the id of the child process)
- in the child process, `fork` will return a zero value

So, in other words: when you write:

```
if (fork()) {
    // Block "If"
} else {
    // Block "Else"
}
```

the original process will execute the "block if" and the child process will execute the "block else".

`pipe` returns two file descriptors, one that can be used to write into the pipe, and the other one that can be used to read from the pipe. So when you write:

```
int ipc[2];
pipe(ipc);
```

Whatever you write in `ipc[1]` can be read when you read `ipc[0]`.
In other words, that's a good way to communicate between the two process created by `fork`.

In your example the child process (in the "else") writes data in `ipc[1]` and the original process (in the "if") reads it.

You created a child process writing data in a pipe while your original process reads data from the pipe.

Comment: The `fork()` function returns an `int`, and `int` values are not null.  Null applies to pointers.  The `fork()` function returns `-1` if it fails, `0` in the child, and a positive integer in the parent.